# erlang:monitor and 'DOWN' message

Tags: erlang

When studying carefully "gproc" project's gproc_tests.erl file. I have found the following code.
The "goodbye" message is send before "erlang:monitor/2", I think it is possible that 'DOWN' message won't be received. Is it correct? If so, the two lines should be switched, right?

```
t_simple_aggr_counter() ->
    ?assert(gproc:reg({c,l,c1}, 3) =:= true),
    ?assert(gproc:reg({a,l,c1}) =:= true),
    ?assert(gproc:get_value({a,l,c1}) =:= 3),
    P = self(),
    P1 = spawn_link(fun() ->
                gproc:reg({c,l,c1}, 5),
                P ! {self(), ok},
                receive
                {P, goodbye} -> ok
                end
            end),
    receive {P1, ok} -> ok end,
    ?assert(gproc:get_value({a,l,c1}) =:= 8),
    ?assert(gproc:update_counter({c,l,c1}, 4) =:= 7),
    ?assert(gproc:get_value({a,l,c1}) =:= 12),
    P1 ! {self(), goodbye},  %<<===========This line
    R = erlang:monitor(process, P1), %<<======This line
    receive {'DOWN', R, _, _, _} ->
        gproc:audit_process(P1)
    end,
    ?assert(gproc:get_value({a,l,c1}) =:= 7).
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

the erlang:monitor/2 call will still generate a {'DOWN', ...} message to the calling process even if the monitored process has already died.

for example:

```
1> F = fun() -> io:format("finished.~n") end.  
#Fun<erl_eval.20.111823515>
2> Pid = spawn(F).
finished.
<0.45.0>
3> erlang:monitor(process, Pid).    % process Pid has already exited.
#Ref<0.0.0.76>
4> flush().
Shell got {'DOWN',#Ref<0.0.0.76>,process,<0.45.0>,noproc}
ok
```

Comment: There is also a flush option to the demonitor call that may come in handy.

Answer (score 5):

According to documentation [erlang:monitor/2](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erlang.html#monitor-2): *A 'DOWN' message will be sent to the monitoring process if Item dies, **if Item does not exist**, or if the connection is lost to the node which Item resides on.*